# Can I use source control from Visual Studio Team Services using VS 2015 Community edition

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I want to install Visual Studio Community edition and I need to use Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) free account as source control.

The information on the [visual studio site](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs) seems to indicate no functionality available under the Team Foundation section. But from a lot of searching online I have found conflicting advice and people say that they have been able to use it with an in-house TFS etc.

Can I use the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with the Visual studio Team Services free services like source control, work item tracing, branching/merging code etc?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can, but some features may not be available.

Comment: Have you tried source control as that is what I need most?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES. You can use any VS edition to connect to Visual Studio Team Service.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can use source control with my exiting free account on visualstudio.com ?

Comment: @VaibhavGarg Yes, you can use it from VS\Team Explorer just the same as other VS edition.